# Link main logo to custom URLs instead of homepage, with WordPress Avada child theme?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

I'm trying to customize Avada to link the main site logo to a custom URL when you're on certain pages. I copied *logo.php* into the child theme and added this:

```
        <?php $standard_logo = Avada()->images->get_logo_image_srcset( 'logo', 'logo_retina' ); ?>
        <!-- custom standard logos -->
        <?php
        //Binghamton
        if (is_page( array (194, 376, 534, 329, 499, 489, 479, 476, 467)))
        {
          $standard_logo['srcset'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/broadway-binghamton-logo.png';
          $standard_logo['url'] = $standard_logo['srcset'];
          $retina_logo['srcset'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/broadway-binghamton-logo-retina.png';
          $retina_logo['url'] = $standard_logo['srcset'];
        }

        //Erie
        if (is_page( array (248, 382, 589, 926, 1542, 1537, 1514)))
        {
          $standard_logo['srcset'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/broadway-erie-logo.png';
          $standard_logo['url'] = $standard_logo['srcset'];
          $retina_logo['srcset'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/broadway-erie-logo.png';
          $retina_logo['url'] = $standard_logo['srcset'];
        }
        ?>
        <!-- standard logo -->
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url_raw( $standard_logo['url'] ); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $standard_logo['srcset'] ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( $standard_logo['width'] ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( $standard_logo['height'] ); ?>"<?php echo $standard_logo['style']; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?> alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo_alt_attribute ); ?>" retina_logo_url="<?php echo esc_url_raw( $standard_logo['is_retina'] ); ?>" class="fusion-standard-logo" />

        <?php
        if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'mobile_logo', 'url' ) && '' !== Avada()->settings->get( 'mobile_logo', 'url' ) ) {
            $mobile_logo = Avada()->images->get_logo_image_srcset( 'mobile_logo', 'mobile_logo_retina' );
        ?>
            <!-- custom mobile logos -->
            <?php
            //Binghamton
            if (is_page( array (194, 376, 534, 329, 499, 489, 479, 476, 467)))
            {
              $mobile_logo['srcset'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/broadway-binghamton-logo.png';
              $mobile_logo['url'] = $mobile_logo['srcset'];
            }

            //Erie
            if (is_page( array (248, 382, 589, 926, 1542, 1537, 1514)))
            {
              $mobile_logo['srcset'] = '/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/broadway-erie-logo.png';
              $mobile_logo['url'] = $mobile_logo['srcset'];
            }
            ?>
            <!-- mobile logo -->
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url_raw( $mobile_logo['url'] ); ?>" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $mobile_logo['srcset'] ); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( $mobile_logo['width'] ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( $mobile_logo['height'] ); ?>"<?php echo $mobile_logo['style']; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?> alt="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo_alt_attribute ); ?>" retina_logo_url="<?php echo esc_url_raw( $mobile_logo['is_retina'] ); ?>" class="fusion-mobile-logo" />
        <?php } ?>
```

which changes out the logos to match the correct cities, but **I need the city logos to link to the city pages, instead of the homepage.**

http://nac.flywheelsites.com/broadway-in-binghamton/ displays the Binghamton logo but links back to http://nac.flywheelsites.com/ currently.

I tried:

```
$standard_logo['/broadway-in-binghamton/'] = $standard_logo['srcset'];
```

but I don't think that's right. Similar questions say to go into the *header.php* file and find your logo class, but this theme doesn't store it there. Is there a way to insert custom URLs right within the *logo.php* file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is only about the `<img>`. When i check your website, i see that both logo's (normal & retina) are wrapped in a link: `<a class="fusion-logo-link" href="http://nac.flywheelsites.com/">`. You need to find the source of that link (probably header.php).

OR

Avada is a massive theme, there's probably a filter for the logo link you can use to change it. I don't use Avada that much, I suggest you ask them.

---

UPDATE, after finding the correct Avada logo link filter `avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes`

```
add_filter('avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes', 'broadway_logo_link_modify');
function broadway_logo_link_modify() {

  $link = esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

  if (is_page( array (248, 382, 589, 926, 1542, 1537, 1514))) {
    $link = 'http://nac.flywheelsites.com/broadway-in-binghamton/';
  }

  // another option with which you don't have to add every page id
  $current_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($current_url, 'http://nac.flywheelsites.com/broadway-in-binghamton/') !== false) {
    $link = 'http://nac.flywheelsites.com/broadway-in-binghamton/';
  }

  $link_arr = array(
    'class' => 'fusion-logo-link',
    'href' => $link,
  );

  return $link_arr;

}
```

Ofcourse you have to extend the snippet to fit your needs, but you'll get the idea. Place it in your functions.php (not logo.php).

Comment: Thanks but I want to change the URLs for multiple pages, so all of the pages with the Binghamton logo link to the Binghamton page, Erie logo to the Erie page, etc. It's not as simple as editing 'logo_custom_link' within the theme for this reason.

Comment: well it kinda is. In short, find the correct filter or source file. Do a check on what page you're currently on -> set correct link. That's it. When you find the correct source/filter i can help you furthur with this.

Comment: I manage a few sites with the Avada theme, checking now for you.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did find this avada_logo_anchor_tag_attributes File: Avada/templates/logo.php Description: Filters the HTML attributes on the site logo anchor tag. Default Value: `array( 'class' => 'fusion-logo-link', 'href' => ( $custom_link = Avada()->settings->get( 'logo_custom_link' ) ) ? esc_url( $custom_link ) : esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ), )` in Avada Hooks: Actions and Filters

Comment: lol, yeah i just found it also, that's the correct filter. I'll create a snippet for you one sec.

Comment: See my updated answer, please set it as accepted if you like my solution, Thanks :-) !

Comment: Thank you! I will for sure. I appreciate your kindness! This goes in child _functions.php_ file correct?

Comment: I've added another url checking option, see my updated answer. Then you don't have to add every page ID. _'Set and forget'_ ;-)

Comment: Might it be a different filter? I was getting _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /www/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/functions.php on line 37_ so I added ; to the last statement (even though it should be optional) and that removes the parse error, but logos are no longer clickable

Comment: can you share the code you placed in functions.php, use your question post. -- aha, i used the key 'url' in `$link_arr`, it should be 'href'. See updated answer.

Comment: You are a hero! That's the last thing I would have spotted. Perfect! It's working, just need to clean it up for all the pages now. :) yay